# How to translate a 2007 sympy/sage/python code to a modern day sympy/python code?

Tags: python, sympy, algebra, sage

Me struggling with the General Number Field Sieve : round 2 ! As usual : english is not my first langage so 'sorry for bad english'.
So : I'm trying to implement this algorithm and to do it I'm heavily relying on sympy.
But I'm also basing parts of my work on the code of Pr. William Stein (https://wstein.org/misc/aly-lll/gnfs.html), written in python/sympy/sage in 2007.

In it, there is this peice of code (which, of course, happens to be one of the most important) :

```
def find_kernel_vectors(M):
    return M.kernel().basis_matrix().rows()    [1]
```

It will be applied the matrix :

```
M = Matrix(GF(2), len(sel), ev)    [2]
```

where `sel` is a list and `ev` the coefficients of the matrix, which are each either 0 or 1.

However, when I copy-paste it, adding `from sympy import Matrix, GF`, I run in quite a lot of troubles.

Upon execution of [2], I get the error message `GF(2) is not an integer`
I looked up how to use matrices in sympy and from what I gathered, only the list of coefficients in an acceptable input.

So I decided to define M as follows in order to be able to test [1] :

```
M = Matrix(ev)
```

And upon execution of 1, I get the error message `MutableDenseMatrix has no attribute kernel`

The thing is, it's not the first time that things like this happen, because Pr. Stein was coding in a 2007 version of python/sympy/sage.

I don't really think that the issue with [2] is an actual issue because, as I said, the coefficients of my matrix are already 0 or 1 (i.e. elements of GF(2)), however I'm not sure about it. But I'm sure about the fact that [1] is a big issue that I don't have any idea to solve.

I beleive it all boils down to the translation between 2007 sage/sympy/python to modern day python, so if someone knows how to do it, it would save my code.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You need to understand that sage and sympy are different things. Sympy is used internally as part of sage but the code you would write for sage is different from the code you would write for sympy. You need to use this code with sage I think but it looks like you're using it directly with sympy.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But I don't want to use sage, I want to use python (with the module sympy). So I know this raw sage code won't work. But I have no idea how to translate it into working python code

Comment: You will probably need to change the code quite a lot then so it is best to try and understand what each part does and then see how to do the same thing in sympy rather than trying to change the code one piece. I'm guessing that `kernel` in sage is similar to `nullspace` in sympy although it looks like they do not return results in the same form.

Comment: Regarding "it's not the first time that things like this happen, because Pr. Stein was coding in a 2007 version of python/sympy/sage": I don't see any evidence that he was using `sympy` directly in this code. The lines you quote work in current Sage, so as @OscarBenjamin says, you're really asking how to translate (modern day) Sage code into sympy code.